# Implementing a 2d array as a field on a ScriptableObject in unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Some quick background: I'm making a 2D game, and I'm storing abilities as ScriptableObjects for ease of implementation.

I'm looking to implement a 2D array (or at least something functionally similar) as a field for my ability ScriptableObject:

[image]

I'm still new to programming, so I've mostly been looking up tutorials on various concepts that I'm unfamiliar with, and I followed this tutorial to create a script that has a 2D array of bools that would be functionally similar to what I was looking for (Panel oirign would be a seperate field that I would set manually, the bools would just determine which panels were hit): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoHc-Lz9Lsc

My plan was to make a script like that (but 3x8) and attach it to each ability similar to how I attach the prefab for the FX. My thought was that if I were to do that, each ability would have its own instance of that script, and as such its own array of panels that were marked as "true" that I could reference. However, I seem to be unable to attach the script to my ScriptableObject at all. I called the class `RangeResolver` (what the tutorial video used "TestScript" for) and tried setting a `public RangeResolver attackRange` field in my ability ScriptableObject, but I cannot drag or select a script onto that field in the inspector.

I'm completely at a loss on how to proceed. If anyone has any ideas on how I can implement a 2D Array on a ScriptableObject as a field and how I can access the information in said array, I would be super grateful!

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use a string to represent the 8x3 grid by a string of three lines. Add the following field to your `Ability` class:

```
[Multiline]
public string attackRange = "XOOOOOOO\nOZOOOOOO\nXOOOOOOO"
```

The inspector should now show a field:

```
XOOOOOOOO
OZOOOOOOO
XOOOOOOOO
```

Where X represents yellow, Z blue and O grey. The letters can be changed in the inspector to customize the attack pattern. 
You can then write a for-loop that reads the `attackRange` string line by line and calculates the parameters you want.

Source for the `Multiline` parameter: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/424874/showing-a-textarea-field-for-a-string-variable-in.html

Comment: That's certainly a clever solution for it. I tried it out, but the kerning of strings in the inspector and the higher potential for errors on my end (accidentally use 9 characters instead of 8, fatfinger a wrong character, etc. easy to find and fix, but I'd like a less error-prone method) made it less than ideal, so I continued to look for other solutions. I ended up getting that 2D bool array from the tutorial working, and I decided to go with that. Thank you for your input though, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to using the 2d bool array from the tutorial ended up being much simpler than I thought it would. In the tutorial, the user created a `TestScript.cs` that only had 1 field which called the `ArrayLayout` class, which is where they defined the array of arrays that was used for their 2D array. I was attempting to call the actual `TestScript` class instead of the `ArrayLayout` class itself, so by calling `public ArrayLayout attackRange`, it worked exactly in the manner that I had hoped, at least for the bool array. I'm going to go with a manual setting of the origin panel and the bool array as the highlighted panels as my solution.